# Pythonic way to get text from table in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to retrieve the contents of a table from inside our ERP system and store it in a dictionary.

The challenge is the cells are merged when there is repeating values such as `Part No`, `Description` and `Operation` in the screenshot example.

I would love to know how to do this Pythonically, all of my ideas would result in a royal mess of how to do this.

The expected result would be a list of dictionaries, with a dictionary for every row/item in the Bill of Materials.  For example, the top row item would look like this with the other rows being further entries into the list:

```
bom_data = [ 
        {'bom_component_data':{ 'Component Part/Item': 'WP106519 Rev.A'
                                , 'Component Name': 'Disk'
                                , 'Sub Components': 1
                                , 'Active': True
                                , 'Quantity': '1 pcs/pc'
                                , 'Operation': '75-Issue Material'
                                , 'Description': 'Disk'
                                , 'Part_No': 'Part_No_from_page'}
         }
         ]
```

I've been able to identify the elements of interest on the page and will show them in the code snippets below.
First is the column headers, denoted by the tag `th`:

```
print('Table column headers')
bom_table_headers = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')
for bom_table_header in bom_table_headers:
    print(bom_table_header.text)
```

Returns:

```
<Table title> Rev.B Bill of Materials
Part No
Description
Operation
Quantity
Component Part/Item
Component Name
Sub Components
Active
Note
```

I don't want to grab `<Table title> Rev.B Bill of Materials` but the rest of these are items I do want as keys in my dictionary.

The next snippet shows the table row headers, denoted by `tr`:

```
print('Table row contents')
bom_table_contents = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
for bom_table_content in bom_table_contents:
    print(bom_table_content.text)
```

Returns:

```
Table row contents
BackWikiAddUpload
WP106295 Rev.B Bill of Materials
Part No Description Operation Quantity Component Part/Item Component Name Sub Components Active Note
WP106295 Rev.B Disk 75-Issue Material 1 pcs/pc WP106519 Rev.A Disk 1
Disk 130-Turn OD, Front Face 0.166 each/pc WS100028-22-22-07 Box,Plywood,Slip-Over,22x22x7 per Standard Drawing WS100028
1 each/pc WS100039 Pad, Corrugated, Double wall, 21x21x.25, Plain 200
0.042 each/pc WS100021 Pallet,Reconditioned Wood,48 x 48 Runner Type,2-Way Entry, 3" Wing Style. Double runners in the center and 5/8 top boards.
```

And the last snippet shows the cell contents, denoted by `td`:

```
print('Table cell contents')
table_row_items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
for table_row_item in table_row_items:
    print(table_row_item.text)
```

Returns:

```
Table cell contents
BackWikiAddUpload

WP106295 Rev.B
Disk
75-Issue Material
1 pcs/pc
WP106519 Rev.A
Disk
1

Disk
130-Turn OD, Front Face
0.166 each/pc
WS100028-22-22-07
Box,Plywood,Slip-Over,22x22x7 per Standard Drawing WS100028

1 each/pc
WS100039
Pad, Corrugated, Double wall, 21x21x.25, Plain 200


0.042 each/pc
WS100021
Pallet,Reconditioned Wood,48 x 48 Runner Type,2-Way Entry, 3" Wing Style. Double runners in the center and 5/8 top boards.
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the expected result?

Comment: @amarynets, I added this in the main question per your request.  The expected result would be a list of dictionaries, with a dictionary for every row/item in the Bill of Materials.